# First Chern class for smooth line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles

For holomorphic line bundle we define its first Chern class by exponential sequence $$0\to \mathbb Z \to \mathcal O \to \mathcal O^* \to 0 $$
and we can similarly define Chern class for smooth line bundle by the short exact sequence 
$$0\to \mathbb Z \to \mathcal C^\infty \to (\mathcal C^\infty)^*\to 0$$

Then there is a natural morphism from the first short exact sequence to the second one, so there is a natural map $H^2(\mathbb Z)\to H^2(\mathbb Z)$. Is this map isomorphic? Similarly, is the map $H^1(\mathcal O^*)\to H^1((\mathcal C^\infty)^*)$ just the natural map of on equivalent classes of line bundles?

In fact I am almost sure this is true (because they looks natural), but I do not know how to show this formally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ in your morphism of short exact sequences is just the identity, and so induces an isomorphism on $H^*(X;\Bbb Z)$.

The second and third maps are inclusion, and think about what this says at the level of building up a vector bundle from transition functions: given a representative for an element of $H^1(X;\mathcal O^*)$, we have charts $U_i \subset X$ and holomorphic maps $U_i \cap U_j \to \Bbb C^\times$ that we think of as transition functions, the way to glue $U_i \times \Bbb C$ to $U_j \times \Bbb C$ over the overlap. The corresponding element of $H^1(X;(\mathcal C^\infty)^*)$ is *the same maps* $U_i \cap U_j \to \Bbb C^\times$, but we have forgotten that they are holomorphic (and just remembered that they are smooth). Thus the line bundle we construct is *the same smooth manifold* (it has the same charts and transition maps!), but we have forgotten the holomorphic structure it naturally inherits.

So the conclusion you get is that the map $c_1: H^1(X;\mathcal O^*) = \text{HolLineBun} \to H^2(X;\Bbb Z)$ factors through $H^1(X;(\mathcal C^\infty)^*) = \text{SmLineBun}_{\Bbb C}$.

(That is, the first Chern class is really an invariant of smooth complex line bundles, and to take the first Chern class of a holomorphic line bundle, just forget that it's holomorphic!)

Comment: Maybe stupid but why identity map must induce isomorphism on cohomology? I think this is not directly followed from definition.

Comment: @UserX I think it is direct: the induced map on the level of cocycles is the identity, as it is on the level of coboundaries. It induces the identity on cohomology.